# Open a JFrame from another, without opening a brand new one every time

Tags: java, jframe, listener, action, frame

So basically I have a 2D game, (basically a link to the past knock off) and when you press the e key, the invetory opens up, and hides on close. The problem is, every time I hit the e key, it opens a NEW invetory with all the initial values, I want it to open a new one after the initial. Would post code, but it's very long and messy(I'm a beginner)

Comment: I'd consider using a popup panel which can overlayed on you game, possible via the glassPane (assuming you're using Swing)

Comment: Why not reuse the same JFrame, showing and hiding it with `setVisible()`? Just create it once somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you need to provide an Inventory JFrame from a Main JFrame when 'e' key is pressed and hide it when the Inventory JFrame is closed. Try the following example:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private Inventory inventoryFrame;

public Main()
{
    inventoryFrame = new Inventory();
    this.setTitle("Main");
    this.setSize(500,500);
    //when 'e' is pressed, show the inventory frame
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("invoked "+e.getKeyChar());
            if(e.getKeyChar() == 'e' || e.getKeyChar() == 'E')
            {
                inventoryFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String... s)
{
    new Main().setVisible(true);
}

}


public class Inventory extends JFrame {

public Inventory()
{
    //initialize the values here...
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.setTitle("Inventory");
    //on closing event... just hide it rather than closing it.
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
}


}
```

Basically, Main class keeps one object of Inventory JFrame and makes it visible when 'e' is pressed and, whenever inventory is closed, its simply hidden because the default close operation set for the Inventory frame is HIDE_ON_CLOSE.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you! it really helped!